# How do I submit the token in the FunCaptcha callback function?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, bots, captcha, 2captcha

Trying to bypass FunCaptcha using Selenium Python. I saw this question was asked before here but there were no answers. After I get the token, how do I submit it in the callback function? What should I execute? I'm able to change fc-token to the new token, but I don't know how to submit it

Answer (score 0):

What page? On outlook works this:

```
"postMessage(JSON.stringify({eventId:'challenge-complete',payload:{sessionToken:'" + token + "'}}),'*')"
```

where `token` is recived token from 2captcha

Answer (score 0):

I'm also finding out, I use this but return undefined `const token = "384177ea88a37f887.2783594605|r=eu-west-1|meta=7|meta_height=325|metabgclr=%23ffffff|metaiconclr=%23757575|mainbgclr=%23ffffff|maintxtclr=%231B1B1B|guitextcolor=%23747474|lang=ru|pk=B7D8911C-5CC8-A9A3-35B0-554ACEE604DA|at=40|ag=101|cdn_url=https%3A%2F%2Fclient-api.arkoselabs.com%2Fcdn%2Ffc|lurl=https%3A%2F%2Faudio-eu-west-1.arkoselabs.com|surl=https%3A%2F%2Fclient-api.arkoselabs.com|smurl=https%3A%2F%2Fclient-api.arkoselabs.com%2Fcdn%2Ffc%2Fassets%2Fstyle-manager" postMessage(JSON.stringify({eventId:'challenge-complete',payload:{sessionToken: token }}))`

Answer (score 0):

it will be inactive from November 2023

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).